# Tcpdf not correct show symbols

Tags: php, tcpdf

I need add to pdf different symbols, but sometime it get wrong result like this:

[image]

Original text is 'Sorry für die Stille'

How can I solve this?

Font settings:

```
$pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetFont (PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', 9 , '', 'default', true );
```

Comment: Are you sure that your font supports umlauts?